# Wired Ethernet Unmanaged while using a bridged network adaptor

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, deja-dup

My server (22.04) uses netplan to manage the ethernet connection and create a bridged network device for a VM. This works fine, the server and VM both get internet access but GNOME says that the wired connection is unmanaged in the top right menu and ethernet doesn't appear in settings.

This isn't an issue except that I use Deja Dup for backups over the network to a second NAS and this won't occur as it thinks it's not connected to the network. I can fix this by editing my netplan file to include 'renderer: NetworkManager' but this then breaks the bridged VM adaptor and the VM fails to get internet/LAN access.

This is the netplan file, /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices
network:
#  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [ eno1 ]
      addresses: [192.168.1.3/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  version: 2
```

This works for the VM but not backups and if the renderer line is uncommented this works for the backups (GNOME says connected etc) but not the bridged VM!

How can  I solve this so that I have the bridged adaptor for the VM but also have GNOME think it's 'connected' so Deja will work too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update, managed to fix it myself.
Cleared my netplan file back to default:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Rebooted to ensure everything was changed over then followed this guide https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-add-network-bridge-with-nmcli-networkmanager-on-linux/

This setup my bridged adaptor so the VM works fine now, host server still has internet and GNOME recognises it as connected so backups via Deja can now proceed.